# where to find PhoneGap tutorials?

Tags: java, android, iphone, html, cordova

Hi friends I am an Android Developer and I have java background,
But in my company most of the projects we have to developed in android and I-Phone.
and my company want me to learn Phone-gap or something that where can I developed project in one technology and run in both Android and I phone or Blackberry Etc.

It will be y appreciating if you guys help me by providing links of some good basic start up tutorials for phone gap .

PS.
In My Company's Project we don't require much of core functionality of android we just have project which require simple logic and user interface.

Thaks In Advance.

Comment: @Raynold Please read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap

Comment: @PradeepSimha, Thank you, i know Phonegap already.

Comment: why shouldn't i move to phone-gap ? or Is there something else which is better than phone gap for Cross platform functionality?

Comment: @user2176734, you can definitely move to phone-gap.. :)

Comment: Because PhoneGap is horrible compared to a native application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start building cross-platform mobile apps! From Getting Started Guides to Docs, we've got everything you need to get started with PhoneGap.[Reference](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/index.html)